# XPath to find dynamic parent/ancestor element from current element?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing selenium tests for a dynamic material angular web app.  I can successfully locate the element I want, but then I need to go back up the DOM to the nearest `<mat-form-field>` tag.  I know how to navigate upwards using xpath (`By.XPath("../..")`) but I don't always know how many elements there will be until I get to the `<mat-form-field>` tag.  How could I locate that element dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//target[@id="i1"]/ancestor::mat-form-field[1]
```

will select the closest ancestor `mat-form-field` element from the targeted `target` element.